# How to install grid_renderer on Linux?

Tags: mapnik, installation

I'm having a hard time installing [grid_renderer](http://trac.mapnik.org/wiki/MapnikRenderers) on Ubuntu Maverick (10.10). I've followed [these instructions](http://trac.mapnik.org/wiki/UbuntuInstallation) but when I compile the mapnik branch I always get this error (http://pastebin.com/Txc5Wt9W):

```
[...]
scons: *** [bindings/python/mapnik_python.os] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a bug in the code and it's already fixed in the [latest mapnik branch](http://trac.mapnik.org/changeset/2787).

Comment: welcome to GIS Stack Exchange :) Thank you for taking the time to come back and indicate the problem has been solved. You can mark mark your own answser as the best correct one after a day or so. It would be a better answer for those that come after if it also contained some info about the particular bug that's been fixed, and perhaps a link to it's entry in a tracker or fix report.

Comment: Thanks, @matt-wilkie. I've edited my message and marked my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a solution here : http://lists.berlios.de/pipermail/mapnik-devel/2008-September/000715.html

A mismatch in user configuration, solved by building as root.